# testing with images using jest for a next.js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, next.js

I have followed the instructions provided [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#handling-static-assets). This works and compiles fine.

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    /* Handle image imports
    https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#handling-static-assets */
    '^.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|avif|svg)$':
      '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
  },
```

As expected when I try to test a file with a static file import jest doesn't throw an error.

I have a Next.js/React component that trys to render an `<Image>` (from Next.js)

```
return (
    <Image width={list.width} height={list.height} src={list.src} alt='Chord Information'/>
)
```

In my application `list` returns (from a `console.log` message);

```
{
    height:"24px",
    width:"24px",
    src:"/a/valid/path/"
}
```

If I try to use this in a test without a `width/height` jest tells me to add height, width or fill. if i use `list.src` in `src` jest tells me thats `list.src` is `undefined`.

When I log out the value of `list` during a test it returns `test-file-stub`. This is expected as per the instructions for handling static files. In fact, any `list` property returns `undefined` because its not an object, its a `string`.

Assuming that all if this is supposed to be happening, i'm not sure how to test files that have images, since I need to provide `<Image/>` with valid data or it will fail and putting conditional logic in place seems wrong.

How am I supposed to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by following the instructions [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/testing#setting-up-jest-with-babel), specifically changing `__mocks__\fileMock.js` from

```
module.exports = 'test-file-stub';
```

to

```
module.exports = {
  src: '/img.jpg',
  height: 24,
  width: 24,
  blurDataURL: 'data:image/png;base64,imagedata',
}
```